# Check to see whether View Model is visible in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to check whether a particular view model is visible or not. I have a property on my view model that exposes whether it is visible or not and this is set when it becomes visible. However, I would like to grab the current view models and check this property. How do I get a handle on the view model?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22492065/373321 might help with this - visibility is controlled by "presentation" - and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/n42-is-my-viewmodel-visible-can-i-kill.html too